# In firebase_messaging dev14 How to open a screen when user clicks on the notification (background)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I Want to know how to open a new screen when the notification is tapped. In my case, if I click on it, it do nothing... I want that (depending of the notification) it opens the app and opens a new given screen

This is the json I'm sending now:

```
'{"notification": {"body": "${body}", "title": "${title}", "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"}, "priority": "high", "to": "MYTOPIC"}';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) to generate named routes and then when the notification is clicked your onLaunch() method is executed wherein you can extract the path from the deeplink and pass it to the navigator.

Now lets say you have 2 screens users screen and user profile screen. You'll have two routes defined in your router class.

```
MaterialRoute(page: UsersScreen, path : '/users'),
MaterialRoute(page: UserProfileScreen, path : '/users/:userId?'),
```

In the notification data payload you can pass the data link as /users or /users/:userId? , extract the data on onLaunch triggered from terminated state and pass it to your navigator. You can have a look at their example to get a better understanding of the named routes.

Comment: But i'm using the version dev-14... onLaunch has been deprecated and onMessageOpenedApp never gets called

Comment: This issue you're facing is on iOS or android?

Comment: Android, I did not tested in ios

Comment: I'm using this version other than this every version seems to have problem for me , try this version     firebase_messaging: 6.0.9

Comment: Thank you and upvote the question if you feel it useful